# Resize UIImageView for leftCalloutAccessoryView in Map Pin Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, mapkit

I am developing and app in Xcode (objective-c) and I have a problem. I have set a leftCalloutAccessoryView image in my map pins but my problem is that the image size is too big. If it is possible, I want to resize the UUImage without changing the real size of the image, because if I change the size of the image, the image gets worst quality and I can see it pixeled.

This is my viewForAnnotation methof whre I have implemented my leftCalloutAccessoryView:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil )
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin2@2x.png"];
    }
    else {
        //[mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }


    /**Pone una imagen a cada map pin leftimage**/
    UIImageView *leftIconView;
        leftIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"80_grados.png"]];


    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;
    leftIconView.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    leftIconView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    leftIconView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    /********/


    UIButton *pinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = pinButton;

    return pinView;
}
```

[image]

This is what I want to get without changing the image size because it reduces their quality:
[image]

Do you know how can I size my `leftIconView`? 
Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: set frame for leftIconView simple and change the content mode of image view to aspectfit

Comment: @Vinodh Can you explain to me how to do it? I have a low level of Xcode but I am trying to improve every day. I have tried leftIconView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; but it doesn't works. Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: then try adding frame after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used sample image to fix your issue .Please use the below code to fit the image into pinview

```
 UIImageView *leftIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bartender"]];
    leftIconView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    leftIconView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, pinView.frame.size.height- 20, pinView.frame.size.height - 20);
    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;
    leftIconView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    leftIconView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

And also please find the attached screenshot for reference

[image]

Comment: It works great. Thank you very much for your time and your response!